# How to have more than one child on AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle> Iusing flutter and getting 'Value' isnt defined when it is required by Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am getting a 'value' isnt defined on my widget but the widget itself requires this param.
This is flutter and below is the code.

```
child: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
                value: SystemUiOverlayStyle( ' <- here is where it is saying its not defined
                  systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
                  systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                ),
                Widget: Provider<DeepLinkBloc>(
                  create: (context) => _bloc,
                  dispose: (context, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
                  child: MaterialApp(
```

I have tried using children and seperating widget out but still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Follow this pattern

```dart
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
  value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
    systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  ),
  child: Provider(
    create:
```